# Skin problem with richfaces on Weblogic 10.3

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, seam, web.xml

I have a big problem with richfaces and weblogic 10.3.
I use seam 2.2.0 on weblogic for my project.

All jsf and richfaces fonctionnalities work fine except one. The skin doesn't work, nothing is skinned so my application has none css and it's very dumpy.

What is wrong in my configuration ?

Thanks.

Here is my richfaces configuration in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.seam</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
<param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
<param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
<param-value>enable</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
<param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
<filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/seam/resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
<param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
<param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<security-constraint>
<display-name>Restrict raw XHTML Documents</display-name>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

- If this happens in all your pages that follow a specific Facelets template, and does not happen for others,then there is something wrong in your Facelets template (a tag not closing correctly?) You can check this by creating a simple page with a couple of components and seeing if they are skinned correctly.
- It may be your security constraint. Put your pages under a dir (for example, /pages/*.xhtml) and restrict that one.